# Как скрыть элемент по id используя Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как можно скрыть элемент из списка нажав на кнопку hide?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="cards__list" v-if="items.length > 0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="hideItem(item.id)">hide</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                items: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.fetchItems();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchItems() {
                this.loading = true;
                fetch("/api/articles")
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(res => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.items = res.data;
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));

            },
            hideItem(id) {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Для этого необязательно использовать vue, можете добавить метку javascript на вопрос - и будет вам решение на чистом js. Вам же на деле если не нужен state и реактивность - можно просто сделать скрытие элемента и всё. А для этого хватит и обычного javascript. Тут больше вопрос - что понимать под скрытием - навешивание стиля display:none или visibility:hidden

Comment: а если просто сделать display:none как это правильно сделать в этом случае?

Comment: добавьте в item поле display:true/false, и управляйте видимостью элемента с помощью v-if

Comment: Да уж, это точно. Кому `style display`, кому `slice array` )))

Comment: @РустамГимранов, а кому ни то и ни другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
       
        items: [
            {
               display: true
            },
            {
                
                display: true
            },
            {
                
                display: true
            },
            {
                
                display: true
            }
        ]
    },

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
 
<div id="content">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div v-if="item.display"> {{index}}
      <button @click="item.display = false">Hide</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```